# Creating a sql table with a column for each date in a range and the corresponding day in the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry if the title's a bit confusing, what I'm trying to get is basically this:

```
|one |two|1/1/2017|2/1/2017|3/1/2017 |4/1/2017|ect.... |1/1/2027|
|    |   |Monday  |Tuesday |Wednesday|Thursday|ect.... |Monday  |
|    |   |        |        |         |        |ect.... |        |
|    |   |        |        |         |        |ect.... |        |
```

A column for each date in a range (1/1/2017 - 1/1/2027) with the corresponding day in the next row, the first two columns are for other data.
Thanks for the help

Comment: This sounds like a dreadful table design.  Is there any chance you could span days across rows instead?

Comment: Reallly, james? 3655 columns on one table? Even if it's supported, mostly likely it's far less usable or performing than a row-based approach. Why not store as row and output as column using `PIVOT`?

Comment: This is quite possibly a stupid idea, but i need to have a few years worth of days and be able to add more rows as needed + the data entered needs to be checked with a foreign key.  this is the best solution i could think of. any other ideas would be _very_ appreciated.

Comment: @james, I'd need to understand to be able to help, let's consider this, why in the upcoming code you are tending towards @T1 instead of @T2? (*don't worry about difficulty of inserting/generating data for now, only focus on reading/storage*) `DECLARE @T1 TABLE([2017/01/01] varchar(10), [2017/01/02] varchar(10), [2017/01/03] varchar(10)); INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday'); SELECT * FROM @T1; DECLARE @T2 TABLE(YourDate datetime, YourDay varchar(10)); INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES ('2017/01/01', 'Sunday'), ('2017/01/02', 'Monday'), ('2017/01/03', 'Tuesday'); SELECT * FROM @T2;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to just get the day of the week? if so, instead creating a table for it I would recommend using datepart to get the day of the week.

you would get today's day of the week with something like this:

```
select datepart(weekday,GETDATE())
```

for example if the return value is 5 that'd be Thursday, if the return value is 1 then it'd be Sunday. obviously this depends on which day is set to be the first day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

```
     declare @a1  date

     create table  #date
      ( 
      date_stamp varchar(90)
      ,weekday  varchar(80)
       )

      set @a1='1/1/2017'
      while @a1<='1/1/2027'
      begin 
       insert into  #date
       select @a1,
            case 
                when datepart(weekday,@a1)=2 then 'Monday' 
                when datepart(weekday,@a1)=3 then 'Tuesday' 
                when datepart(weekday,@a1)=4 then 'Wednesday' 
                when datepart(weekday,@a1)=5 then 'Thursday ' 
                when datepart(weekday,@a1)=6 then 'Friday' 
                when datepart(weekday,@a1)=7 then 'Saturday' 
                when datepart(weekday,@a1)=1 then 'Sunday' 
              else '' end  
       set @a1=DATEADD(DAY,1,@a1)
      end 

  ----to show the date
     select * from #date
```